# How can I organize large form elements on a page?

Tags: html, css, controls

I have large number of form elements (80+) to design on the html page. Is there nice way to organize and design those elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with @Pranay Rana about the pattern of breaking the fields up in sections, make it more semantic and give your AT (assistive technololgy) users a break and organize your forms and section *related items* off in [`<fieldset>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/forms.html#the-fieldset-element) elements.

Answer (score 1):

put you control in Sections of Div and than minimize/maximize the dive

example : http://dyndiv.markusbordihn.de/example/moveable-min-max/
when you click cross sign it minimize and maixmize div....same thing you can do it by using +/- sign something like expading control. but this do involve javascript.

or

Make use of Tabs to organize control. : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I like to put it as TAB with focus.. can u give me some sample links